# using fs module in typescript and export a class

Tags: typescript, angular

In my Angular2 application, I'm trying to import fs and use it in my class then export it so that I could import in my app.component.ts

```
// foo.ts
import * as fs from "fs"
export class Foo {
  foo1() {
    fs.readFile('file.txt', (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err
      return data
    })
  }
}

// app.component.ts
import { Foo } from './foo.ts'
.....
export class AppComponent {
  foo: Foo;
  constructor() {
    this.foo = new Foo();
  }
}
```

but my npm just told me that `404 GET /fs`
I think I have successfully import `fs`, but I can't use `Foo.foo1()`
Does any one know that?

I tried to add `/// <reference path='../node/node.d.ts' />` and it still can not work

node: v.4.3.0

Comment: I think you are mixing your server side and client side code.

Comment: yap. pretty sucks!

Answer (score 3):

> import * as fs from "fs"

Your browser cannot access the file system on the server. `fs` should not be loaded in the browser.

Comment: Oh, I knew it. Thanks!

Comment: How about using angular2 in Electron? Still no?